# C Linked List Code Style

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is my beginner code for dealing with a linked list. I appreciate any comments on structure, logic, formatting, and anything small or large. I have run the code using gcc and tested the small `main` function using Valgrind with no errors.

**ll.h**

```
#ifndef LL_H
#define LL_H

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ll_LinkedList ll_LinkedList;
typedef struct ll_LinkedListNode ll_LinkedListNode;

struct ll_LinkedList {
  ll_LinkedListNode* head;
};

struct ll_LinkedListNode {
  void* data;
  ll_LinkedListNode* next;
};

ll_LinkedList* ll_create    ();
void           ll_destroy   (ll_LinkedList* ll);

void           ll_append    (ll_LinkedList* ll, void* data);
void*          ll_at        (ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos);
void           ll_clear     (ll_LinkedList* ll);
void           ll_insert    (ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos, void* data);
void*          ll_remove    (ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos);
bool           ll_is_empty  (ll_LinkedList* ll);
size_t         ll_length    (ll_LinkedList* ll);
void           ll_prepend   (ll_LinkedList* ll, void* data);

#endif
```

**ll.c**

````
#include "ll.h"

void ll_append(ll_LinkedList* ll, void* data) {
  ll_insert(ll, ll_length(ll), data);
}

void* ll_at(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos) {
  ll_LinkedListNode* node = ll->head;
  while (pos > 0) {
    node = node->next;
    pos--;
  }
  return node->data;
}

void ll_clear(ll_LinkedList* ll) {
  ll_LinkedListNode* node = ll->head;
  while (node != NULL) {
    ll_LinkedListNode* next = node->next;
    free(node);
    node = next;
  }
  ll->head = NULL;
}

ll_LinkedList* ll_create() {
  ll_LinkedList* ll = malloc(sizeof(*ll));
  ll->head = NULL;
  return ll;
}

void ll_destroy(ll_LinkedList* ll) {
  ll_LinkedListNode* node = ll->head;
  while (node != NULL) {
    ll_LinkedListNode* next = node->next;
    free(node);
    node = next;
  }
  free(ll);
}

void ll_insert(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos, void* data) {
  assert(pos <= ll_length(ll));
  
  ll_LinkedListNode* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
  new_node->data = data;

  if (ll->head == NULL) {
    new_node->next = NULL;
    ll->head = new_node;
  }
  else if (pos == 0) {
    new_node->next = ll->head;
    ll->head = new_node;
  }
  else {
    ll_LinkedListNode* node = ll->head;
    while (pos > 1) {
      node = node->next;
      pos--;
    }
    new_node->next = node->next;
    node->next = new_node;
  }
}

bool ll_is_empty(ll_LinkedList* ll) {
  return ll_length(ll) == 0;
}

size_t ll_length(ll_LinkedList* ll) {
  size_t length = 0;
  ll_LinkedListNode* node = ll->head;
  while (node != NULL) {
    node = node->next;
    length++;
  }
  return length;
}

void ll_prepend(ll_LinkedList* ll, void* data) {
  ll_insert(ll, 0, data);
}

void* ll_remove(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos) {
  assert(pos <= ll_length(ll));

  if (pos == 0) {
    ll_LinkedListNode* rm = ll->head;
    ll->head = rm->next;
    void* data = rm->data;
    free(rm);
    return data;
  }
  else {
    ll_LinkedListNode* h = ll->head;
    ll_LinkedListNode* t = h->next;
    while (pos > 1) {
      h = h->next;
      t = t->next;
      pos--;
    }
    h->next = t->next;
    void* data = t->data;
    free(t);
    return data;
  }
}

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
  int d = 4;

  ll_LinkedList* ll = ll_create();
  ll_insert(ll, 0, &c);
  ll_insert(ll, 0, &b);
  ll_insert(ll, 0, &a);
  ll_insert(ll, 2, &d);
  ll_insert(ll, 4, &d);

  ll_clear(ll);
  ll_insert(ll, 0, &c);
  ll_insert(ll, 0, &b);
  ll_insert(ll, 0, &a);
  printf("Removed: %d\n", *((int*) ll_remove(ll, 0)));
  printf("Removed: %d\n", *((int*) ll_remove(ll, 0)));
  printf("Removed: %d\n", *((int*) ll_remove(ll, 0)));

  ll_insert(ll, 0, &c);
  ll_insert(ll, 0, &b);
  ll_insert(ll, 0, &a);
  printf("Removed: %d\n", *((int*) ll_remove(ll, 1)));

  if (!ll_is_empty(ll)) {
    printf("It is not empty.\n");
  }

  ll_clear(ll);
  if (ll_is_empty(ll)) {
    printf("It is empty.\n");
  }

  ll_append(ll, &a);
  ll_append(ll, &b);
  ll_append(ll, &c);
  ll_prepend(ll, &c);
  ll_prepend(ll, &c);

  printf("Length: %ld\n", ll_length(ll));
  for (size_t i = 0; i < ll_length(ll); ++i) {
    printf("%d, ", *((int*) ll_at(ll, i)));
  }
  printf("null\n");

  ll_destroy(ll);
  return 0;
}
```
````

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recommend some additional compiler warning options:

```
gcc -std=c17 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds  -Wstrict-prototypes    -Wconversion    252015.c    -o 252015
252015.c:22:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 ll_LinkedList* ll_create    ();
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
252015.c:60:16: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 ll_LinkedList* ll_create() {
                ^~~~~~~~~
252015.c:144:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int main() {
     ^~~~
```

---

Most of the `#include` lines are not needed for the header file, only by the implementation.  In particular, these three can be moved to `ll.c`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

---

`while (node != NULL)` is a little long-winded; it's idiomatic to simply write `while (node)`.  Some coding standards disallow that, in which case you may be required to use the long form.

---

```
  ll_LinkedList* ll = malloc(sizeof(*ll));
  ll->head = NULL;
```

```
  ll_LinkedListNode* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
  new_node->data = data;
```

These are problems waiting to happen - `ll` or `new_node` might be a null pointer, and we failed to check.

---

```
void* ll_remove(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos) {
  assert(pos <= ll_length(ll));
```

`ll_remove()` is a public function, so we're in no position to vouch for the condition we're asserting.  That should be a real check rather than an `assert()`:

```
   if (pos <= ll_length(ll) {
       return NULL;
   }
```

I don't like the way this function walks the list twice (once in `ll_length()` and then again to actually do the insert.  It would be more efficient to just check for going off the end of the list as we traverse it, just once.  `ll_append()` traverses the list *three* times!

---

`ll_destroy()` could simply delegate most of its work to `ll_clear()`.

---

The special-casing for element 0 in many functions could be removed by using an empty element as list head.

---

A final style point that might be contentious - I would write `sizeof *p` rather than `sizeof(*p)`, only using parens around the argument in the rare cases you actually need to use a type name as argument to the `sizeof` operator (and I do prefer a space after the keyword, unlike the non-alphabetic unary operators such as `-` and `++`).   So `sizeof (struct tm)`, for example.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed pass! I've made a number of changes thanks to this answer.

Comment: Regarding "while (node != NULL)", that's debatable. The MISRA C guidelines actually say that this should *not* be done. More specifically, they say "if (node)" should be reserved for Boolean values, because using it to test for zero/non-zero or null/non-null is a common cause of people misunderstanding the code when maintaining it. The OP should be aware of the idiom, but they shouldn't necessarily adopt it.

Comment: I'd recommend keeping the ```include```s and using header guards. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers

Comment: @thzoid: The point is that those includes are not needed by *users* of the library, only by the implementation.  So users shouldn't have to pay the price, and they don't belong in our header.  If you read [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1804719/4850040) to the question you linked, that's exactly what it recommends, too.

Comment: Direct quote: "*if the implementation file needs some other headers, so be it, and it is entirely normal for some extra headers to be necessary. But the implementation file (`magicsort.c`) should include them itself, and not rely on its header to include them. The header should only include what users of the software need; not what the implementers need.*"

Comment: @toby-spleight My bad, I misread your answer and didn't realize OP wrote the includes into the header.

Answer (score 11):

### Design

Your list includes the head of the list.

```
struct ll_LinkedList {
   ll_LinkedListNode* head;
};
```

You could make a lot of your code a lot simpler by including two other values (the tail and the length).

```
struct ll_LinkedList {
   ll_LinkedListNode* head;
   ll_LinkedListNode* tail;
   size_t             size;
};
```

This would make sure you don't have to keep calculating the size and would make appending really easy.

### Code Review:

```
#include "ll.h"

void ll_append(ll_LinkedList* ll, void* data) {
  ll_insert(ll, ll_length(ll), data);            // doubles the cost of the insert
                                                 // you have to traverse the list
                                                 // twice.
}
```

---

What happens if `pos` is beyond the end?

```
void* ll_at(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos) {
  ll_LinkedListNode* node = ll->head;
  while (pos > 0) {
    node = node->next;
    pos--;
  }
  return node->data;
}
```

---

You should validate that ll is not `NULL` before assigning.

```
ll_LinkedList* ll_create() {
  ll_LinkedList* ll = malloc(sizeof(*ll));
  ll->head = NULL;
  return ll;
}
```

---

Simplify the destroy:

```
void ll_destroy(ll_LinkedList* ll) {
  ll_clear(ll);
  free(ll);
}
```

---

```
void ll_insert(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos, void* data) {

    // assuming pos is in range.    
    while (pos > 1) {
      node = node->next;
      pos--;
    }
```

---

Some repeated code you could remove from the if statement.

```
void* ll_remove(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos) {
  if (pos == 0) {

    // STUFF
    void* data = rm->data;
    free(rm);
    return data;
  }
  else {
    // STUFF
    void* data = t->data;
    free(t);
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This included a number of suggestions -- I accepted the current answer because it came first.

Comment: @sdasdadas Do not worry, just upvote any answer you feel tackles your problem. :-)

Comment: Disagree with tripling the size of the head node.  When linked list are used a lot in user code, _many_ of them are empty.  The size of an empty LL is good to keep small.  As far a having ready access to the head and tail, the "head" node can save the tail instead and have the tail.next point to the head.

Answer (score 6):

For a beginner the code is neat. Most is already given by the previous, much more elaborate answer.

*One thing though w.r.t. coding:*
C is unique in that it can use *aliases*, pointers to a variable/field.

For instance below `current` first is an alias of `head` and after that of a node's `next`. With `*current = ...` you can fill the original variable.

```
void ll_insert(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos, void* data) {
  assert(ll != NULL);
  // Not needed: assert(pos <= ll_length(ll));
  
  ll_LinkedListNode** current = &ll->head;
  //while (*current != NULL && pos > 0) {
  while (*current && pos > 0) {
    current = &(*current)->next;
    --pos;
  }
  // Maybe check here that pos reached 0.
  ll_LinkedListNode* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = *current;
  *current = new_node;
}
```

As you see this gives very compact code.

ll_LinkedListNode's struct declaration could move to the .c implementation with a bit of trickery.

In an other language it is customary to hold in ll_LinkedList redundantly the *list size* for faster operations.

Comment: We don't call that an alias though, it's a pointer to a pointer. I'm sure there are other languages besides C and C++ which can do this! Note that if you use pointers to pointers, you can call yourself a two-star programmer :)

Comment: @G.Sliepen yes _alias_ (_aliasing_) is a term I interned studying programming language design and compiler construction in Computer Science. Being a pointer to a pointer, to an existing variable or field, such pee2pees should be used locally in a smaller scope than the pointed to pointer. Yes there are some other languages, but mainstream Java cannot do this.

Comment: Thank you @JoopEggen, I have been trying to understand the double pointers in most linked lists I find and this is helpful. I will also migrate the length to be a struct member. Could you elaborate on how to move the struct declaration into the .c file?

Comment: I am not active in C since sufficient years. Then I did #ifndef's so one would have a typedef void* LinkNodePtr for all API users, and in the C typedef struct {...} *LinkNodePtr. Check whether this trick is still done, maybe nicer today.

Comment: The `typedef` trick is still done, but considered bad style by many here since it hides C's own way of writing a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

**Use `const` when able**

Functions like `ll_at()` and `ll_length()` could code with `const` to better convey code's usage and allow some select usages and optimizations.

```
// void* ll_at(ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos);
void* ll_at(const ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos);

// size_t ll_length(ll_LinkedList* ll);
size_t ll_length(const ll_LinkedList* ll);
```

**Code looks nice, but ...**

Pretty layout is work.  IMO, not worth the effort/time to code and *maintain* versus simply using an auto-formatter.  (Consider work incorporating the `const` idea above.)

```
ll_LinkedList* ll_create    (      void);
void           ll_destroy   (      ll_LinkedList* ll);

void           ll_append    (      ll_LinkedList* ll, void* data);
void*          ll_at        (const ll_LinkedList* ll, size_t pos);
void           ll_clear     (      ll_LinkedList* ll);
```

vs.

```
ll_LinkedList * ll_create(void);
void ll_destroy(ll_LinkedList *ll);
void ll_append(ll_LinkedList *ll, void *data);
void* ll_at(const ll_LinkedList *ll, size_t pos);
void ll_clear(ll_LinkedList *ll);
```

I'd have comments per function, so there common manual format layout is not important.

**Apply**

Consider an *apply* function, something that applies the function to every link's data.  Very useful.

```
int ll_apply(ll_LinkedList* ll, int f(void *state, void *data), void *state) {
  ll_LinkedListNode* node = ll->head;
  while (node != NULL) {
    int retval = f(state, node->data);

    // maybe break on non-zero?
    if (retval) return retval;
        
    node = node->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Use correct specifier with `size_t`**

```
// printf("Length: %ld\n", ll_length(ll));
printf("Length: %zu\n", ll_length(ll));
```

**Could collapse code**

```
if (ll->head == NULL) {
  new_node->next = NULL;
  ll->head = new_node;
}
else if (pos == 0) {
  new_node->next = ll->head;
  ll->head = new_node;
}
```

vs

```
if (ll->head == NULL || pos == 0) {
  new_node->next = ll->head;
  ll->head = new_node;
}
```

**Include trick**

When the unnecessary `#include`s move from `ll.h` to `ll.c`, include `ll.h` there first:

```
// ll.c
#include "ll.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

This helps verify `ll.h` does indeed compile on its own.

**Lack of comments**

IMO, the .h file  deserves a fair amount of comment to let users know what the set does.  Assume the user does **not** have access to the .c file.